# scroll views working fine in iOS 7 with problems in iOS6

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

I hate iOS scroll views with auto layout, they are driving me crazy!:-D

I have found a method which works perfectly on iOS 7 to use scroll views:

I put the scroll view directly in the main view, attaching the scroll view to the edges of the super view(top,bottom leading and trailing space equals to 0).

Then I put a UIView into the scroll view attached to the edges of the scroll view, (top,bottom leading and trailing space equals to 0).

Then I set the height constraint of the most internal view, I link it at my ViewController class, and I modify its value programmatically.
Or, if the view it's 'static' I put every component using the storyboard into the internal UIView, starting with the one at the Top attached to the top of the super view, the one under, attached with the constraint 'Vertical Spacing' referred to the one over him..and so on... Until the last, which is also attached to the bottom of the UIView..

Everything works fine in iOS 7, it's perfect, but iOS 6 is messing around with the constraint.
When I first launch the view everything is perfect, but it seems to recalculate the constraints even on the didappear(and in a bad way), in fact, if I leave my view while it's scrolled down, when I come back to it(let's say we are in a navigation controller) , is like it's everything 'moved up' and the components at the top are hidden.

Is there a way to make scroll views work in both iOS 6 and iOS 7, I'n thinking at two storyboards as the only solution, please tell me there is another way... :-)

thanks everyone, I post two images explaining my problem, taken from the top of the screen:
[image: Correct, at first launch]
[image: Messed up, after going back]

Answer (score 0):

Well uncheck use `AutoLayout` in file inspector and try.